# How can I use / copy a terraform output value to a file at a specific path in a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, automation, terraform, google-cloud-run

I'm running a small cloud run with Terraform on GCP. I have a certain environment variable values that must be set in a correct path `/web/values.py` in the container. This file is copied to a Dockerfile since its values are needed for the app to run.

One of them is supposed to be an output of a Redis instance which is being created by Terraform too.

Output.tf

```
output "host" {
  description = "The IP address of the instance."
  value       = module.memorystore.host
}
```

/web/values.py (that I copy to my dockerfile)

```
key=value
key=value
redis_host=ip_host
```

Is there a way I can channel the Terraform output to the Dockerfile on subsequent Terraform runs seeing I have a functional CI CD with cloud Build. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you setting the config in the container image? A better approach is to have your application get the environment config from environment variables or at runtime so that your image can stay the same in different environments. You might want to look at https://12factor.net/config and also https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/environment-variables

Comment: One way to get terraform outputs via bash cli is: `terraform output host` & you can parse or use that how you need.

Comment: @scotttheos did you have an opportunity to try the suggestions above? Does it answer your question?

Comment: @FaridShumbar the suggestions above needed me to change the code design that my client wasn't able to embrace. However what I did was use an entrypoint in the container to copy the env (output) to the desired path.

The runcloud terraform supports entrypoint commands [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_run_service#command)

Comment: @scotttheos so it looks like you found a solution. Please consider posting it as the answer to this thread so it helps to other community members. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the @scotttheos comment, the solution was to use an entrypoint in the container to copy the env (output) to the desired path.

The runcloud terraform supports [entrypoint commands](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_run_service#command)